# Android and SqlServer 2005

Tags: android, web-services

Is there any way to connect to a SQL Server from an Android application and execute/query SQL statements using Web Service?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will simply have to access the server via a web connection. I would strongly suggest you write server-side scripts for sql statements. Then you can access the information those serverside scripts provide with a HttpClient. Sample code below.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(new URI("www.example.com"));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
```

Make sure you do all networking in a [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Also you will need modify your manifest file for Internet permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Thanks.. That works Fine.. Now I need the code to update data back to web service.. Suppose its two string values.. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean send data back to the web server? You will have to program some server-side script to accept inputs. Be careful because anyone could post data to your server-side script if they are clever.